# Получение уникальных символов строки

Tags: java

Нужно перебрать все символы строки и если оный отсутствует в результирующей строке - добавить его в неё. Вот что у меня получилось:

```
String wordsChangeNotRepeat = "";
for (char c : wordsChange.toCharArray()) {
    if (!wordsChangeNotRepeat.contains(c)) //тут подчёркивает с
        wordsChangeNotRepeat += c;
}
System.out.println(wordsChangeNotRepeat);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените

```
if (!wordsChangeNotRepeat.contains(c))
```

на

```
if (wordsChangeNotRepit.indexOf(c) == -1)
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо проверки каждый раз `wordsChangeNotRepeat` можно использовать `HashSet`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
for (char c : str.toCharArray())
{
    if (!set.contains(c))
    {
        sb.append(c);
        set.add(c);
    }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

На небольших строках разница заметна не будет, однако, например, на строке из 10 миллионов символов, диапазон charcode-ов которых составляет 1074, разница заметна:

```
indexOf: 1180ms
HashSet:   77ms
```

Так как итоговая строка получается достаточно короткая, то преимущества от использования `StringBuilder` вместо `resultString += c` в плане времени выполнения не наблюдается, однако в общем случае рекомендуется использовать для таких целей `StringBuilder`.